# Best options available for Application (Sitecore Website) & Infra Monitoring

Tags: infrastructure, health-monitor

Please recommend some of the best options to monitor web application, SOLR VMs, Webapps. we have our sitecore application hosted in Azure PaaS.
Though we are using a 3rd party tool it is not efficient. Also, if any specific section (content) of a website is down, we would want the website monitoring tool to alert.

Answer (score 1):

As the application is hosted in Azure, so you can get utilize Azure services like:

**Azure Application Insights**: Application Insights is a feature of Azure Monitor that provides extensible application performance management (APM) and monitoring for live web apps

*Setting up Azure Application Insights for Solr*: [How to setup Application Insights for a Solr service hosted on Azure PaaS](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/27400/how-to-setup-application-insights-for-a-solr-service-hosted-on-azure-paas)

**Azure Monitor**: Azure Monitor helps you maximize the availability and performance of your applications and services. It delivers a comprehensive solution for collecting, analyzing, and acting on telemetry from your cloud and on-premises environments.

**Azure Advisor**: Azure Advisor is a Microsoft Azure service that provides recommendations based on your deployed Azure services configuration. By analyzing data from various telemetries, it helps you optimize your Azure configuration using the five pillars of the Microsoft Azure Well-Architected Framework as a baseline

Additionally, you could use a third party tool like **New Relic** as well. Link: https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/infrastructure/microsoft-azure-integrations/get-started/activate-azure-integrations/